# Request in Postman returns success, but when I do the same Request in Python it returns 504

Tags: python, postman, http-post

I'm trying to make a request post in Python, but it's returning 504 Gateway Time-out, but this same request is giving 201 success in postman

this is my code in python:

```
import requests
url = "URL"

payload = {
     'token_master' : 'token',
     'created_at' : 'selected date'
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, timeout=360)

print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
print("Response:", response.text)
```

#I didn't put the real data in url and token_master

Comment: What kind of payload does the server expect? If it expects JSON, you need `json=payload`, not `data=payload`.

Comment: The obvious answer would be that the two scenarios **aren't** the same -- there is some difference between them that you have overlooked.  Can you show screenshots of the postman scenario?

Comment: `data=payload` sends it as URL-encoded data rather than JSON.